# Making terminal settings permanent even after restart

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I am trying to lock the view settings on terminal. Everytime I restart Mac or close all the terminal windows; upon re-opening the windows default to the initial configuration, as though the settings have not been saved.

Is there a way to make the preferences permanent?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by creating a profile in Terminal→Preferences→Profiles and then setting the profile I created to be the profile for new windows on startup in Terminal→Preferences→General.

In my case, I wanted a black background and blue text and use fork of the Hack font.  So on Profiles tab of Terminal's Preferences I created a new profile with the "+", named it, and set the settings the way I wanted them.

[Preferences→Profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LjvX.png)

Then switched to the General tab of Terminal's Preferences and in the drop down for "On startup, open New window with profile" I selected the profile I created.

[Preferences→General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BduBB.png)

Then close out of Preferences. Exit Terminal.app then reopen Terminal.app and I get the settings I setup regardless if I quite and reopen Terminal.app, open multiple Terminal windows or even restart the computer.

So unless I have misunderstood what kind of settings you are referring to, this is an easy and quick way to do it.